# DC block using microstrip line

Tags: power, amplifier, microwave

While implementing an RF amplifier circuit, I came across the fact that micro-strip RF chokes are better for narrowband applications and easy to realize than physical inductor.

My question is whether it is possible to implement DC blocks using micro-strip line. If it is possible what are the formulae/relations I can use to implement DC blocks using micro-strip lines?

Thank you!

Comment: Micro-strip rf choke (inductor) I get but DC block(ing) is done with capacitors not inductors or do you mean some else?

Comment: Your fequency=? Will a quarter wave impedance inverter be too big?

Comment: Knowing the minimum and maximum frequencies that need to be passed through is crucial to answering this question.

Comment: My frequency of operation is 2.45 GHz. @JImDearden, yes I get your point DC blocking is done using capacitors my question is can we replace these capacitors with micro-strip line, the way we do it for inductors (quarter wave match) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally no, the capacitance you get from small gaps in microstrip lines is too small to be useful as a DC block.

If combined with a (relatively) large frequency selective structure like a coupler, then you can get DC isolation from input to output.

For a narrowband DC block, use a small cheap ceramic capacitor. For a wideband DC block, use an expensive large capacitor specified for the job, as cheap large capacitors tend to have high a frequency resonance that kills their performance.

Comment: One more question is, the peak rf voltages will be very high, can these capacitors sustain such voltages?

Comment: Which capacitors? Oh, *these* capacitors. Yes, these capacitors can sustain such high voltages. But be careful, *those* capacitors cannot.

Comment: sorry for ambiguity there! My question is can ceramic capacitors handle higher voltage levels? As high as around 400 V?

Comment: If you look at AVX capacitors, just their ordinary SMD NP0s have ranges up to 500v, ATC's power capacitors start at 1500v

Answer (score 0):

There are microstrip capacitor designs which, obviously, block DC (Unless it is arcing, but then you have a different problem).

Reference:
[Agilent Microstrip capacitor](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5989-8912EN.pdf)

Comment: What problem we can face if use micro-strip capacitors? What about interdigital capacitor?